# Why do I get an Error 404 (The requested resource is not available.) on Tomcat 7.0.70 when my HTML file is in the WebContent folder?

Tags: java, html, tomcat, http-status-code-404, webcontent

I keep getting error 404 when trying to access an HTML file in my Dynamic Web Project.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>NMWebServices</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>NMServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.nilaymodi.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NMServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Inspiration Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>testing</p>
</body>
</html>
```

my java rest service class

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/inspiration")
public class Endpoints {

@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getInspiration() {
    Inspiration inspiration = InspirationFactory.generate();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String result = gson.toJson(inspiration, Inspiration.class);

    return Response.ok(result, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}

@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response testConnection() {
    return Response.ok("Sucess! Service is running.", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

which works completely fine at the url "localhost:8080/apps/inspiration/"

my context root is "apps" and I am trying to hit the HTML file with the url 
"localhost:8080/apps/inspiration.html" which is the url eclipse gives when I right click on the HTML file and go to run on server. I'm using Tomcat v7.0.70

any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have anything written to serve static content. You'll need to do [something like this](http://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/).

Comment: thanks for the reply.

I did find the following in the server.xml:

    <Context docBase="NMWebServices" path="/apps" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:NMWebServices"/>
      

NMWebServices is the name of my project in Eclipse and apps is the context-root. 

I'm not sure what I should add to this based on the link you provided.

Comment: aha - found a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965738/how-to-serve-static-files-in-my-web-application-on-tomcat

Comment: But I am wondering if it is possible to serve the static content with the same url pattern as the dynamic content.