# How to configure tomcat to see images in html in browser

Tags: java, html, image, tomcat

I am trying to include an image (my company logo) in an HTML page.
When my HTML is not hosted on tomcat and I give absolute file path in HTML, everything works fine and I am able to see the image

The following works perfectly fine outside tomcat:

```
<footer>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <center><p>Powered by: </p>
  <img src="D:\MyImagesFolder\logo.png"  /></center>
</footer>
```

BUT. When I access the same HTML from localhost:8080/myform, the image does not load

### I have tried the following

1. Added context.xml in my web project's META-INF and added the following to it

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context path="/MyContext/images" docBase="D:\MyImagesFolder" crossContext="true"/>
```

AND in the HTML

```
  <img src="MyContext/images/logo.png"  />
```

then added a leading slash to make it

```
<img src="/MyContext/images/logo.png"  />
```

### **No LUCK**

### Then I tried the following

2. Under apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21\conf I created a folder Catalina and a folder localhost inside Catalina

Created an XML file named MyContext#images.xml in localhost which was having the following

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/MyContext/images" docBase="D:\MyImagesFolder" crossContext="true" />
```

and in the HTML I tried

```
<img src="MyContext/images/logo.png"  />
```

and

```
<img src="/MyContext/images/logo.png"  />
```

### **NO LUCK**

3. I put my image inside \apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21\webapps\ROOT and 
   in the html

### **NO LUCK**

4. As I am running tomcat inside eclipse, I tried putting MyContext#images.xml in "Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost-config" in eclipse and

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context path="/MyContext/images" docBase="D:\MyImagesFolder" crossContext="true"/>
```

in the XML

and in the HTML I tried

```
<img src="MyContext/images/logo.png"  />
```

and

```
<img src="/MyContext/images/logo.png"  />
```

### **NO LUCK**

What is missing and where?

Comment: https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here - [How to serve static files in my web application on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965738/how-to-serve-static-files-in-my-web-application-on-tomcat)

Simple created a folder WebContent/images , placed my png file there and in teh html

```
<img src="images/gitc_logo.png"  />
```

And now it works..